# replicate iferror and vlookup in a pandas join

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I want to join two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Banner': {0: 'banner1', 1: 'banner2', 2: 'banner3'},
                    'Campaign': {0: 'campaign1', 1: 'campaign2', 2: '12345'},
                    'Country ': {0: 'de', 1: 'it', 2: 'de'},
                    'Date': {0: '1/1/2016', 1: '2/1/2016', 2: '1/1/2016'},
                    'Value_1': {0: 10, 1: 5, 2: 20}})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Banner': {0: 'banner1', 1: 'banner2', 2: 'banner3', 3: 'banner4', 4: 'banner5'},
                    'Campaign': {0: 'campaign1',1: 'campaign2', 2: 'none',3: 'campaign4',4: 'campaign5'},
                    'Country ': {0: 'de', 1: 'it', 2: 'de', 3: 'en', 4: 'en'},
                    'Date': {0: '1/1/2016', 1: '2/1/2016', 2: '1/1/2016', 3: '3/1/2016', 4: '4/1/2016'},
                    'Value_2': {0: 5, 1: 10, 2: 15, 3: 20, 4: 25},              
                    'id_campaign': {0: 'none', 1: 'none', 2: '12345', 3: 'none', 4: 'none'}})
```

**edit**:
let's even imagine the option:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Banner': {0: 'banner1', 1: 'banner2', 2: 'banner3'},
                'Campaign': {0: 'campaign1', 1: 'campaign2', 2: '12345'},
                'Date': {0: '1/1/2016', 1: '2/1/2016', 2: '1/1/2016'},
                'Value_1': {0: 10, 1: 5, 2: 20}})
```

I have to join df2 and df1 on the keys:

- Date
- Campaign
- Banner

The issue here is that when the match under the key "Campaign" is not found, the key should be switched to field "id_campaign".

I would like to obtain this dataframe:

```
df_joined = pd.DataFrame({'Banner': {0: 'banner1', 1: 'banner2', 2: 'banner3', 3: 'banner4', 4: 'banner5'},
                      'Campaign': {0: 'campaign1', 1: 'campaign2', 2: 'none', 3: 'campaign4', 4: 'campaign5'},
                      'Country ': {0: 'de', 1: 'it', 2: 'de', 3: 'en', 4: 'en'},
                      'Date': {0: '1/1/2016', 1: '2/1/2016', 2: '1/1/2016', 3: '3/1/2016', 4: '4/1/2016'},
                      'Value_1': {0: 10, 1: 5, 2: 20, 3: 0, 4: 0},
                      'Value_2': {0: 5, 1: 10, 2: 15, 3: 20, 4: 25}, 
                      'id_campaign': {0: 'none', 1: 'none', 2: '12345', 3: 'none', 4: 'none'}})
```

any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use double [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) by 3 and 2 keys and then fill not match values by [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) from column `Value_1` of `df4`:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df2, df1.drop('Country', axis=1), on=['Date','Campaign','Banner'], how='left')
df4 = pd.merge(df2, df1, on=['Date','Banner'], how='left')

print (df3)
    Banner   Campaign Country       Date  Value_2 id_campaign  Value_1
0  banner1  campaign1       de  1/1/2016        5        none     10.0
1  banner2  campaign2       it  2/1/2016       10        none      5.0
2  banner3       none       de  1/1/2016       15       12345      NaN
3  banner4  campaign4       en  3/1/2016       20        none      NaN
4  banner5  campaign5       en  4/1/2016       25        none      NaN

print (df4['Value_1'])
0    10.0
1     5.0
2    20.0
3     NaN
4     NaN
Name: Value_1, dtype: float64

df3['Value_1'] = df3['Value_1'].combine_first(df4['Value_1']).fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df3)
    Banner   Campaign Country       Date  Value_2 id_campaign  Value_1
0  banner1  campaign1       de  1/1/2016        5        none       10
1  banner2  campaign2       it  2/1/2016       10        none        5
2  banner3       none       de  1/1/2016       15       12345       20
3  banner4  campaign4       en  3/1/2016       20        none        0
4  banner5  campaign5       en  4/1/2016       25        none        0
```

Comment: It works flawlessly: I just need an extra clarification to understand better the join.
If the df1 didn't contain the column "Country", I would I would I get the same df3? I'll edit my question.

Comment: I think both `df1` are same. Maybe some wrong copy.

Comment: Ok, I try explain better my solution: So idea is very easy - if use inner join, all keys have to match. So if use 3 keys  `on=['Date','Campaign','Banner']` and some not match, is omit. and problematic key is in column `Campaign`. so I create another `merge` where is omit this problematic key and you get another output `df4`. But you need only column `Value_1` and need replace all values of `df3['Value_1']` where are `NaN` (not match). So it add value `20` and values in first and second row are not replaced. If my explanation is not clear (I often cannot explain well), give me a question.Thanks

Comment: I'm really sorry, I edited the second variation of df1.